# Installing Lubuntu on a PPC Mac Pro

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu, mac, ppc

I have a Mac Pro (PPC Model, G3 Quicksilver) that I would like to run Lubuntu on. It has two internal HDDS: one is 41GB and the other is 20GB. Mac OS X is already on the 41GB drive, but I would like Lubuntu to be installed on the 20GB drive and pick which to use at boot (like dual-boot, but on two different drives). I can't figure out how to partition the drives during installation.

1. What partitions do I need?
2. What type do they need to be?
3. Where do they need to be mounted?
4. How big do they need to be? I would like the main partition to be 15GB, with swap about 2GB-4GB.

The machine:
1024GB RAM
733 MHz CPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh.

I accidentally clicked Install with "Replace Mac OS X" selected, and it gave me an option to use the other drive instead of the Mac OS X drive.

Case closed.